# Show matched text in tableview search text results

Tags: swift

Attempting to produce search results in a tableview in a format similar to the way Google presents search results. I do not need assistance in adding the attributes. Looking for some guidance on how best to present the matched text as shown below in the Google screen shot example.

The Google Search result example below uses *match* and *found* as search terms.  Note the bold matched text shown within the string.  Google's result shows a portion of the text to show context which is helpful to the user in deciding relevancy. However, the location of the matched text could be deep in a multi line string:

[image: See sample image below]
So far, I have had success referencing a UITextView outlet in a subclassed tableview cell and instantiating the subclassed cell within  `override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`

The assignment of the subclassed cell is:

`let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell2", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCustomCell2`

Using `cell` I am able to reference the UITextView outlet which has access to scrollview functions like `scrollRectToVisible` or `scrollRangeToVisible`.  Using the latter, I pass in a `NSRange` parameter using the first element of an array containing ranges of each matched text.  The latter works when I test the code leaving scrolling enabled. However, `scrollRangeToVisible` gets called every time I scroll through the search results which is annoying and, in any event, I need to disable scrolling.

If I attempt to disable scrolling within `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` immediately AFTER calling `scrollRangeToVisible` on the cell, `scrollRangeToVisible` does not work.

There must be some place within the life cycle of the View Controller to execute `scrollRangeToVisible` after which I can then disable scrolling.  Any thoughts on how to best accomplish this?  Is there a delegate/protocol to use to access the needed sequence of events in the cycle?  Or am I barking up the wrong tree by using a UITextView?

Alternatively, can anyone point me to a github example or stackoverflow question that treats a similar issue?

Comment: "Or am I barking up the wrong tree by using a UITextView?" Well, that was going to be my first thought. It depends on your needs, of course, but if the goal is to look like the google search result screen shot, that's not a text view-like thing but a label-like thing. You would just make a label with an attributed string bolding the matched words and display it.

Comment: The cell I use also includes labels to show title headings etc.   I used UITextView because it can scroll through multi-line text which is what I am working with. The goal is to use a view, perhaps a label, to show the matched words within the context of the surrounding text string. A label does not have the ability to scroll to different ranges within a multi-line string -as far as I know.  Perhaps I take the range of the matched word and expand it to capture a range of text before and after the match range?  I could add the result to a label.